# Sort list on numeric values stored as factor

Tags: r, sorting

I have 4 data frames with data from different experiments, where each row represents a trial. The participant's id (SID) is stored as a factor. Each one of the data frames look like this:

**Experiment 1:**

```
SID     trial   measure
 5402       1  0.6403791
 5402       2 -1.8515095
 5402       3 -4.8158912
25403       1         NA
25403       2 -3.9424822
25403       3 -2.2100059
```

I want to make a new data frame with the id's of the participants in each of the experiments, for example:

```
   Exp1        Exp2        Exp3        Exp4
    5402       22081       22160       25434
   25403       22069       22179       25439
   25485       22115       22141       25408
   25457       22120       22185       25445
   28041       22448       22239       25473
   29514       22492       22291       25489
```

I want each column to be ordered as numbers, that is, 2 comes before 10.

I used **unique()** to extract the participant id's (SID) in each data frame, but I am having problems ordering the columns.

I tried using:

```
data.frame(order(unique(df1$SID)),
           order(unique(df2$SID)),
           order(unique(df3$SID)),
           order(unique(df4$SID)))
```

and I get (without the column names):

```
38  60  16  32  15
2   9   41  14  41
3   33  5   30  62
4   51  11  18  33
```

I'm sorry if I am missing something very basic, I am still very new to R.

Thank you for any help!

Edit:
I tried the solutions in the comments, and now I have:

```
x<-cbind(sort(as.numeric(unique(df1$SID)),decreasing = F), 
         sort(as.numeric(unique(df2$SID)),decreasing = F), 
         sort(as.numeric(unique(df3$SID)),decreasing = F), 
         sort(as.numeric(unique(df4$SID)),decreasing = F) )
```

Still does not work... I get:

```
    V1  V2  V3  V4
    8   6   5   2   
2   9   35  11  3
3   10  37  17  184
4   13  38  91  185
5   15  39  103 186
```

The subject id's are 3 to 5 digit numbers...

Comment: I didn't understand the problem you are facing, please be clear on what are you expecting and what you get

Comment: why do you want a data.frame and not just a list of ids for each experiment?  using a data.frame suggests (1) that you have the same number of participants in each experiment, and (2) the participants on a given row have something in common

Comment: @vdep I updated the question with the information you asked

Comment: @ C8H10N4O2, it does not need to be a data frame, I just want some sort of a table with who participated in what experiment.

Comment: You can try sort(unique(id_column),decreasing=F), but a data.frame can only be created if the number of unique ids across each experiment is same.

Comment: @Sininho better try to create a list with sort function.

Comment: @Tushar, with e.g. cbind? how do I create a list?

Comment: @ C8H10N4O2, sort seems to use the number that internally represents the factor, and not it's level

Comment: @Sininho that's correct, you can do the coercion correctly by `as.numeric(as.character(x))`.  See solution below.

Comment: yeap, as.numeric(as.character(x)) did the trick. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data looks like this:

```
df <- read.table(text="
  SID     trial   measure
 5402       1  0.6403791
 5402       2 -1.8515095
 5402       3 -4.8158912
25403       1         NA
25403       2 -3.9424822
25403       3 -2.2100059",
header=TRUE, colClasses = c("factor","integer","numeric"))
```

I would do something like this:

```
df <- df[order(as.numeric(as.character(df$SID)), trial),] # sort df on SID (numeric) & trial

split(df$SID, df$trial) # breaks the vector SID into a list of vectors of SID for each trial
```

If you were worried about unique values you could do:

```
lapply(split(df$SID, df$trial), unique) # breaks SID into list of unique SIDs for each trial
```

That will give you a list of participant IDs for each trial, sorted by numeric value but maintaining their factor property.

If you really wanted a data frame, and the number of participants in each experiment were equal, you could use `data.frame()` on the list, as in:  `data.frame(split(df$SID, df$trial))`

Comment: The key concept here is how factors work.  Internally, factors are an integer `1,2, .... n` representation of `n` different levels.  Those levels could be something like `c("math","chemistry","philosophy")` if the variable is `subject`, but more confusingly they could be something like `c("5402","2543")`  So to get `c(5402, 2543)` instead of `c(1,2)` you need to first get it as a string (to remove the `c(1,2)` representation) and then read it back in as a number.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose x and y represent the Exp1 SID and Exp2 SID. You can create a ordered list of unique values as shown below:

```
x<-factor(x = c(2,5,4,3,6,1,4,5,6,3,2,3))
y<-factor(x = c(2,3,4,2,4,1,4,5,5,3,2,3))
list(exp1=sort(x = unique(x),decreasing = F),y=sort(x = unique(y),decreasing = F))
```